# How can I prevent TeamCity Cloud Agents (running on Amzon EC2) from leaving defunct volume snapshots when they terminate?

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity, build-agent

I've recently set up TeamCity to use agents running on Amazon EC2. I've been using it for a week or so and noticed my bill was racking up quite quickly. When I looked in my dashboard I had 30 or so snapshots, which I presume I'm being charged for.

TeamCity starts agents on demand and stops them when they've been idle for about an hour. At that point, the instance is deleted. I would expect the corresponding snapshot to be deleted too, but that doesn't seem to be happening, they are piling up like zombies!

When setting this up I followed [Roy Osherove's guide](http://osherove.com/blog/2010/5/31/running-teamcity-from-amazon-ec2-cloud-based-scalable-build.html) and I tried to follow to the letter, but I'm sure I must have missed something. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that those snapshots are indeed the main constituents of your bill? I'm not familiar with the TeamCity agent provisioning, but I doubt that ~30 left over EBS volume snapshots will have any significant impact on your AWS bill, insofar EBS cost usually amount for a fraction of the average AWS bill for any but the most special use cases; instead I'd suspect the created/running/terminated instances themselves to inflict the cost, which you could only remedy by adjusting the TeamCity provisioning algorithm and/or instance type.

Comment: I've given up on AWS, the cost was far more than the benefits and I felt like I wasn't in control. My bill was equivalent to almost $2 per build!! I've gone back to running build agents on-premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a special teamcity-agent image, when add esb volume, check the "Delete on Termination" checkbox.

[image]